# How to create a common lisp (SBCL) vector of a particular type for usage in a usocket?

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

I'm very new to Common Lisp and I am trying to learn how to program using network sockets. In the common lisp [usocket api](https://common-lisp.net/project/usocket/api-docs.shtml) it specifies that the functions `socket-send` and `socket-receive` take a `simple-array (unsigned-byte 8)` buffer.

I'm too new to lisp to understand how to achieve this in sbcl common lisp. It appears I can use the functions `vector` and `make-array` but not `simple-array`, nor how to specify the type as `unsigned-byte 8`.

Is something like the following reasonable and typesafe?:

```
  (let ((buffer (make-array (list-length input))) (input-length (list-length input)) )
    (loop 
      for i upto input-length collect i do
      (setf (nth i buffer) (parse-integer (nth i input))))
    (usocket::socket-send socket buffer input-length)))
```

If not, how do I accomplish making the kind of buffer I need?

Comment: As an aside, for converting properly UTF-8 encoded strings you might want use something like `babel`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CL-USER 25 > (make-array 10
                         :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
                         :initial-element 0)
#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

CL-USER 26 > (describe *)

#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) is a (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) (10))
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      0
8      0
9      0
```

**Mapping:**

```
CL-USER 32 > (map '(simple-array (unsigned-byte 8) (*)) #'char-code "foobarbaz")
#(102 111 111 98 97 114 98 97 122)
```

or simpler

```
CL-USER 33 > (map '(vector (unsigned-byte 8)) #'char-code "foobarbaz")
#(102 111 111 98 97 114 98 97 122)
```

back:

```
CL-USER 34 > (map 'string #'code-char #(102 111 111 98 97 114 98 97 122))
"foobarbaz"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed for creating an array of the proper type! Can you comment on how I can convert an input string to that buffer type and back again? I only implied that in my question but that's the next thing that I need

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! :)